# Fork-server and grandchildren for exec

Tags: c, exec, fork

I need help with fork-server. What I want to do is accept a client then fork to let other clients connect and at the same time redirect stdout & err to client. The client should then be able to send strings that should be exec by the execlp() which is located in a grandchild.

Im not able to locate my logic errors..

In main():

```
    while (1) {

        t = sizeof(remote);

        printf("Waiting for connection.\n");

        s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&remote, &t);

        if (s2 == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        } else {

            printf("Client connected.\n");

            if(!fork()) {

                close(1);
                dup(s2);
                handle(s2);
                exit(0);               
            }
            close(s2);
        }
    }
```

In handle():

```
    char str[100];
    int n;

    while(1) {

        n = recv(client_socket, str, 100, 0);

        if(n <= 0) {

            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        } else {

            if(!fork()) {

                execlp("/bin/sh", "sh","­-c", str, NULL);
                exit(1);
            } 
            wait(0);
        } 
    }
```

The result of execlp is not redirected to the client and gives an error "sh: Can't open c".

Comment: what do you get when you execute this on console "/bin/sh sh ­c"

Comment: I guess because i tested execlp outside fork and it works.

Comment: When I type "/bin/sh sh ­c" in console I get the same error

Comment: What is the value of `str`? Is it properly terminated?

Answer (score 1):

You should write: `execlp("/bin/sh", "sh","-c", str, NULL);` to pass option '-c' to the shell. You are passing option `"c"` which is interpreted as: run the script called `c` which doesn't exist.

See: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh

Another thing: You should NUL terminate your string after reading from it:

```
if(n > 0)
    str[n] = '\0';
```

You should also read only 99 characters as you will write the `'\0'` character at the end of your string.

Comment: Im sorry but misstyped in the question got , "-c",

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the command you try to run isn't in the command search path.

Another reason might be that the string you fetch contains the command *and* its arguments, and passing it as a single argument to `execlp` will pass it as a single argument to the shell so it thinks the whole string is the command.

If it's the last, then you need to split the command and its arguments up in an `argv` like array, and use `execvp` instead.

It is also very important that the string is properly terminated. Does the connect client send with the terminating `'\0'` character? If not then you need to add it yourself (in which case you can only receive 99 characters).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the client, when i change the Var str to "ls" or whatever command it still gives errors.